# Matrix p-Norm Inequality Proof

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

For $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, show:

$\|A\|_\infty \le \sqrt{n} \|A\|_2$

I have seen the following proof on the forum:

Say $e = [1,1,\dots,1]^T \in {\mathbb{R}}^{n} $,

$\|A\|_\infty = \max_\limits{1\le i \le m} \left( \sum^n_{j=1} |a_{ij}| \right) = \|Ae\|_\infty \le\|Ae\|_2 \le \|A\|_2 \|e\|_2 = \|A\|_2 \sqrt{n}$

I don't quite understand the second equality. What if say $a_{ij}$ has negative elements? wouldn't that break the equality?

Comment: I don´t quite understand the first identity, isn´t $||A||_{\infty}$ the maximal absolute value of the entries of $A$? Is $||A||_2$ to be understood as an operator norm with respect to the $2$-norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ or as the $2$-norm of the vector $A$, i.e. as an element of $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$? In the first case the second inequality would be clear by definition of the operator norm.

Answer (score 0):

The $||A||_{\infty}$ norm is basically the maximum of absolute row sums. Here, we are having $m$ rows. Let's say the $k$th absolute row sum is the maximum. If we Let's randomly take the pattern of signs of the elements of $k$th row to be $(+,-,...,-)$.Now consider the vector $e=(+1,-1,...,-1)$. Then $||A||_{\infty}=||Ae||_{\infty}$.From here, other things will follow in the same way.